# Get a string that will be highest alphabetical order

Tags: c#, string, list

It's difficult to say this right. Basically, I have a List, and I need to get back a string which will be the last in that list of alphabetical order. For example:

If I had the list:

```
{ "01", "0a2", "test" }
```

I would need to get back a string that would be next in the alphabetical order, for example "tf"

Comment: You want something `alphabetically higher then 'test'`? Cant you conver them to char and add one to the charcode,

Comment: "test " would be before "tf".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit a hacky answer, but I hope that helps. Assuming you have your strings in a sorted list, I have a litte "quick-and-dirty"-method that generates an item next in alphabetic order:

```
var items = new System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<string, string>();

items.Add("01", "01");
items.Add("02a", "02a");
items.Add("test", "test");

var nextItem = items.Last().Key;

int pos = nextItem.Length - 1;
while (pos >= 0)
{
   if ((nextItem[pos] != 'z') && (nextItem[pos] != 'Z'))
   {
      nextItem = nextItem.Substring(0, pos - 1) +  Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(nextItem[pos]) + 1) + nextItem.Substring(pos + 1);
      break;
    }
    pos--;
 }

 if (pos == -1)
 {
    nextItem += "a";
 }
```

Comment: Interesting answer. Let me try that :)

Comment: I have a slight problem.. Here's what it ends up doing: http://screensnapr.com/v/bI2nyb.png - It starts out fine and then ends up making the same thing over and over. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you don't say in what language?

most languages have a sort function for arrays, which sorts alphabetically. just do the sort then select the last element of the array.

Comment: I know how to sort, but I need to create a NEW string that will be greater in alphabetical order than the ones in the array...

Answer (score 0):

If you always want a string which is alphabetically "last" after all the existing strings, this should work ;)

```
var words = new []{"01","0a2","test"}; 

int maxLength = words.ToList().Max(x => x.Length);

string newWord ="";

for(int i=0;i<maxLength +1;i++){

  newWord+= "z";            

}
```

Comment: the word after "test" is - alphabetically - "tesu" and not "testz" like in your sample.